# Conditionally hide a paragraph in Vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

i have this issue that i am trying to figure. I have a dropdown and the paragraph should only display for first and second option. Now it's easy to do through a button or checkbox. How do i make it through a dropdown.

I have created a codepen for demonstration purposes. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LKYZox. I know the paragraph should be binded to the values but having a hard time in executing.

```
 <div id="app">
 <v-app id="inspire">
   <v-layout row wrap>
  <v-flex xs3>
        <v-select :items="items">
   </v-select>
    </v-flex> 
   <span class="title text-xs-center">How to Show This paragraph for First 
and Second Item only</span>
  </v-layout>  
  </v-app>
 </div>


  new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data(){
   return{
    items: [
    'Item1',
    "Item2",
    "Item3",
      "Item4"
    ]
  }
 }
})
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to bind the selected value of the `v-select` to some data. In the example below I've used `v-model` and the data is called `item`.

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs3>
         <!-- Added a v-model here -->
         <v-select :items="items" v-model="item"></v-select>
      </v-flex> 
      <!-- Added a v-if here -->
      <span
        v-if="['Item1', 'Item2'].includes(item)"
        class="title text-xs-center"
      >
        How to Show This paragraph for First and Second Item only
      </span>
    </v-layout>  
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return{
      item: 'Item2', // <- This is new
      items: [
        'Item1',
        "Item2",
        "Item3",
        "Item4"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

You don't necessarily have to set the initial value of `item` to `'Item2'` but that line does have to be there to create the reactive data property. You can use `null` if you don't want any of the items to be selected initially.

Exactly how you write the `v-if` will depend on the specifics of your scenario. For example, if you wanted to check for the first two items by index it might be `v-if="[0, 1].includes(items.indexOf(item))"`. If `-1` isn't a problem then this could be simplified to `v-if="items.indexOf(item) < 2"`. If the real scenario is a bit more complicated you might want to move the `v-if` expression out to a computed property instead.